# Github sharing widgets

Tags: javascript, github, share

I saw a little sharing widget for github on a jquery plugin's page, but, I don't remember what site it's from. So i've been doing some searching and it doesn't seem to exist so I thought i'd post here and see if anybody else has seen what i'm looking for.

Basically the  widget was the same as a facebook like or tweet button, but when you clicked it, it starred the project on github. I'm totally ok with making a widget with the api, which I am researching right now so see if I can do this.

Anybody seen anything like this in the wild?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [unofficial GitHub buttons](http://ghbtns.com/).

Comment: Yes! Exactly. Everything I googled should have shown this page... Thank you so much!

Comment: @ShanRobertson If you are happy with my answer and would like to resolve your question, please don't forget to mark it as accepted (with the check mark next to the question).

Comment: Note that the readme in the repo that @SimonBoudrias linked to has information on setting up the buttons.